# Run a dynamic SQL query from a stored procedure to populate a GridView

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a dynamic query that adds WHERE clauses according to the parameters received:

```
DECLARE @p1 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p2 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p3 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p4 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p5 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p6 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p7 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p8 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p9 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p10 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p11 varchar(max);
DECLARE @p12 varchar(max);

SET @p9 = 'Acta'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max);

SET @SQL = 
    'SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS [regs]
    FROM [dbo].[DP_Fichas] [F]
    WHERE 1 = 1';

IF(@p1 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '
               AND [F].[ID] = ''' + @p1 + ''''
END;

IF(@p2 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Titulo] LIKE ''%' + @p2 + '%'''
END;

IF(@p3 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Texto] = ''' + @p3 + ''''
END;

IF(@p4 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Fecha] = ''' + @p4 + ' 00:00:00.0000000'''
END;

IF(@p5 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Constitucionailidad] = ''' + @p5 + ''''
END;

IF(@p6 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Comentarios] = ''' + @p6 + ''''
END;

IF(@p7 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idfuente varchar(max)
    SET @idfuente =
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_Fuentes] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p7)
    )
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdFuente] = ''' + @idfuente + ''''
END;

IF(@p8 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idvigencia varchar(max)
    SET @idvigencia =
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_Vigencia] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p8)
    )
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdVigencia] = ''' + @idvigencia + ''''
END;

IF(@p9 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idtipo varchar(max)
    SET @idtipo =
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_TipoFicha] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p9)
    )
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdIdentificacion] = ''' + @idtipo + ''''
END;

IF(@p10 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[NormaNumero] = ''' + @p10 + ''''
END;

IF(@p11 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Publicacion] = ''' + @p11 + ''''
END;

IF(@p12 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[TemaResumen] = ''' + @p12 + ''''
END;

EXEC(@SQL);
```

In this example, only the `@p9` parameter has a value, so the returned SQL command will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [regs]    
FROM [dbo].[DP_Fichas] [F]    
WHERE 1 = 1        
  AND [F].[IdIdentificacion] = '2'
```

This is working just fine when I execute the query, but when I save it to a stored procedure, it comes back empty.

This is the code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEL_DP_Fichas_Buscar_Algoritmo_Contar]
(
    @p1 varchar(max),
    @p2 varchar(max),
    @p3 varchar(max),
    @p4 varchar(max),
    @p5 varchar(max),
    @p6 varchar(max),
    @p7 varchar(max),
    @p8 varchar(max),
    @p9 varchar(max),
    @p10 varchar(max),
    @p11 varchar(max),
    @p12 varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @p1f varchar(max) = @p1;
DECLARE @p2f varchar(max) = @p2;
DECLARE @p3f varchar(max) = @p3;
DECLARE @p4f varchar(max) = @p4;
DECLARE @p5f varchar(max) = @p5;
DECLARE @p6f varchar(max) = @p6;
DECLARE @p7f varchar(max) = @p7;
DECLARE @p8f varchar(max) = @p8;
DECLARE @p9f varchar(max) = @p9;
DECLARE @p10f varchar(max) = @p10;
DECLARE @p11f varchar(max) = @p11;
DECLARE @p12f varchar(max) = @p12;

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max);

SET @SQL = 
    'SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[DP_Fichas] [F]
    WHERE 1 = 1'

IF(@p1 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '
               AND [F].[ID] = ''' + @p1 + ''''
END;

IF(@p2 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Titulo] LIKE ''%' + @p2 + '%'''
END;

IF(@p3 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Texto] = ''' + @p3 + ''''
END;

IF(@p4 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Fecha] = ''' + @p4 + ' 00:00:00.0000000'''
END;

IF(@p5 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Constitucionailidad] = ''' + @p5 + ''''
END;

IF(@p6 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Comentarios] = ''' + @p6 + ''''
END;

IF(@p7 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idfuente varchar(max)
    SET @idfuente =
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_Fuentes] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p7)
    )
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdFuente] = ''' + @idfuente + ''''
END;

IF(@p8 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idvigencia varchar(max)
    SET @idvigencia =
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_Vigencia] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p8)
    )
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdVigencia] = ''' + @idvigencia + ''''
END;

IF(@p9 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idtipo varchar(max)
    SET @idtipo =
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_TipoFicha] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p9)
    )
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdIdentificacion] = ''' + @idtipo + ''''
END;

IF(@p10 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[NormaNumero] = ''' + @p10 + ''''
END;

IF(@p11 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Publicacion] = ''' + @p11 + ''''
END;

IF(@p12 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[TemaResumen] = ''' + @p12 + ''''
END;

EXECUTE (@SQL);
END
GO
```

Whenever I run the stored procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SEL_DP_Fichas_Buscar_Algoritmo_Contar]
    @p1 = '',
    @p2 = '',
    @p3 = '',
    @p4 = '',
    @p5 = '',
    @p6 = '',
    @p7 = '',
    @p8 = '',
    @p9 = 'Actas',
    @p10 = '',
    @p11 = '',
    @p12 = '';
```

I should get 142 as a count result, but I'm getting:

```
Commands completed successfully.

Completion time: 2021-06-15T16:36:31.1131407-05:00
```

I need this stored procedure to fill up a GridView:

```
string spQuerySel0 = "SEL_DP_Fichas_Buscar_Algoritmo";

DataSet dsFlt1;
SqlConnection conFlt1;
SqlDataAdapter daFlt1;
conFlt1 = new SqlConnection(enchufe);
daFlt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(spQuerySel0, conFlt1);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", p1);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", p2);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", p3);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", p4);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", p5);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", p6);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", p7);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", p8);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", p9);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", p10);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", p11);
daFlt1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", p12);
dsFlt1 = new DataSet();
daFlt1.Fill(dsFlt1, spQuerySel0);
gvFichasRes.DataSource = dsFlt1.Tables[spQuerySel0].DefaultView;
gvFichasRes.DataBind();
daFlt1.Dispose();
conFlt1.Close();
```

But I'm getting a null exception, I guess that is because the stored procedure is returning nothing.

I've also tried to add OUTPUT to the query, but It'll break to a "Not found procedure" error.

What can I do here?

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And stop blindly choosing datatypes. Your parameters cannot possibly need varchar(max). Given the names involved, at least some of them should be numeric, not string. Lastly an empty string is not the same as a NULL string. Your tsql code expects NULL values as parameters, not empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of query is known as a [Kitchen-Sink query](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

**You have a number of issues with your current code:**

- `@SQL` should be declared as `nvarchar(max)`
- You should parameterize the dynamic statement, in other words: the parameters should be pushed through via `sp_executesql`
- The same applies to the subqueries, they can be run in the dynamic part
- The parameter types should match the columns they are compared against, which in turn should be fitting for the data in them. I've made a guess at suitable types.
- It's unclear what you hoped to achieve with the extra `DECLARE @p1f` statements, perhaps to avoid parameter sniffing, but that can be avoided with `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`, and in any case doing this dynamically means you probably *should* use parameter sniffing
- In the C# side, you should dispose all SQL objects with `using` blocks
- You should also [avoid `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), specify the parameter types explicitly.

So your final procedure would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEL_DP_Fichas_Buscar_Algoritmo_Contar]
(
    @p1 int,
    @p2 varchar(200),
    @p3 varchar(200),
    @p4 date,
    @p5 char(2),
    @p6 varchar(200),
    @p7 int,
    @p8 int,
    @p9 int,
    @p10 varchar(200),
    @p11 varchar(200),
    @p12 varchar(200)
)
AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) =
    N'
SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[DP_Fichas] [F]
    WHERE 1 = 1'
;

IF(@p1 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N'
               AND [F].[ID] = @p1';

IF(@p2 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N' 
                AND [F].[Titulo] LIKE ''%'' + @p2 + ''%''';

IF(@p3 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N' 
                AND [F].[Texto] = @p3';

IF(@p4 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N ' 
                AND [F].[Fecha] = @p4';

IF(@p5 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N' 
                AND [F].[Constitucionailidad] = @p5';

IF(@p6 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N' 
                AND [F].[Comentarios] = @p6';

IF(@p7 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdFuente] IN
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_Fuentes] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p7)
    )';

IF(@p8 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdVigencia] IN
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_Vigencia] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p8)
    )';

IF(@p9 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[IdIdentificacion] IN
    (
        SELECT
            [X1].[ID]
        FROM [dbo].[DP_TipoFicha] [X1]
        WHERE
            ([X1].[Nombre] = @p9)
    )';

IF(@p10 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N' 
                AND [F].[NormaNumero] = @p10';

IF(@p11 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND [F].[Publicacion] = @p11';

IF(@p12 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQL += N' 
                AND [F].[TemaResumen] = @p12';

EXEC sp_executesql
    @SQL,

  N'@p1 int,
    @p2 varchar(200),
    @p3 varchar(200),
    @p4 date,
    @p5 char(2),
    @p6 varchar(200),
    @p7 int,
    @p8 int,
    @p9 int,
    @p10 varchar(200),
    @p11 varchar(200),
    @p12 varchar(200)',

    @p1 = @p1,
    @p2 = @p2,
    @p3 = @p3,
    @p4 = @p4,
    @p5 = @p5,
    @p6 = @p6,
    @p7 = @p7,
    @p8 = @p8,
    @p9 = @p9,
    @p10 = @p10,
    @p11 = @p11,
    @p12 = @p12;
;

GO
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer with the following lines of code:

```
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @statement = @SQL;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement;
```

I added this to the end of the SP, solved the code issues suggested by SMor and everything worked.

Comment: You should just declare `@SQL` to be `nvarchar(max)` in the first place. And you still have a huge SQL injection problem here. You should be passing through the parameters all the way to `sp_executesql`. Also the subqueries such as `idfuente` should be directly in the dynamic query